# Can I assign a user-assigned identity in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity

I am creating some Azure Logic Apps in order to monitor a workload. These Logic Apps needs a managed identity in order to post metrics to a resource in Azure monitor.

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity), I am sure I can create a system-managed identity for each Logic App and assign the Monitoring Metrics Publisher role to them, but it would be much simpler to create a single user-defined managed identity and assign it to all Logic Apps. I am pretty sure this feature existed, but maybe it was removed.

Do you know any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. It is not available currently.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-logic-apps

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Support for user-assigned managed identities in Logic Apps is now in preview:

[image: support matrix for managed identity]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity#user-assigned

[image: managed identity configuration blade]